# how to print array values using php

Tags: php

I have an array which is populating data from an API, I can print the value of the array but I can't print selected fields from the array. Here is the code snippet through which I can print the whole array...

```
if($apiResponse['response']['status'] === 1) {
        // No errors encountered
        echo 'API call successful';
        echo PHP_EOL;

        echo print_r($apiResponse['response']['data'], true);

        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
    else {
        // An error occurred
        echo 'API call failed (' . $apiResponse['response']['errorMessage'] . ')';
        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Errors: ' . print_r($apiResponse['response']['errors'], true);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Here $apiResponse['response']['data'] is the array which contains the following value...I want to fetch the [name], [offer_url] and [preview_url] values from the array...here is the array which I am able to print...

```
( [3228] => Array ( [OfferUrl] => Array ( [id] => 3228 [offer_id] => 232 
[name] => larl [offer_url] => http://www.nsssa.com/brands/loreacdl-paris.html/?utm_source=abcd&utm_medium=Affiliates [preview_url] => http://www.nsssa.com/brands/larl-paris.html/?utm_source=abcd&utm_medium=Affiliates 
[status] => active [created] => 2014-10-23 03:15:29 [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ) ) 
[3230] => Array ( [OfferUrl] => Array ( [id] => 3230 [offer_id] => 232 
[name] => Schwarzkopf [offer_url] => http://www.nsssa.com/brands/schwarzkopf.html/?utm_source=abcd&utm_medium=Affiliates [preview_url] => http://www.nsssa.com/brands/schwarzkopf.html/?utm_source=abcd&utm_medium=Affiliates 
[status] => active [created] => 2014-10-23 03:16:48 
[modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ) )
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: use echo without print_r

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira...I want to access [offer_url] and [name] and print them only

Comment: $apiResponse['response']['data']['OfferUrl']['name']

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira...its now working...please check the whole array here...http://megaofferz.com/sc/xml1.php...may be you can get some idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just mean this?

```
echo 'Name: ' . $apiResponse['response']['data'][3228]['OfferUrl']['name'] . PHP_EOL;
```

Or

```
foreach ($apiResponse['response']['data'] as $data) {
    echo $data['OfferUrl']['name'] . PHP_EOL;
    // etc
}
```

Comment: @user1413722..yes...but here 3228 is not fixed...you can check the whole array here http://megaofferz.com/sc/xml1.php

Comment: @user1413722...exactly the same i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
dont use print_r and echo in same lines

if($apiResponse['response']['status'] === 1) {
    // No errors encountered
    echo 'API call successful';
    echo PHP_EOL;

    echo $apiResponse['response']['data']['OfferUrl']['name'];

    echo PHP_EOL;
}
else {
    // An error occurred
    echo 'API call failed (' . $apiResponse['response']['errorMessage'] . ')';
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Errors: ' . $apiResponse['response']['errors'];
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access the array keys.

```
$id = $apiResponse['response']['data']['OfferUrl']['id'];
echo "id: $id\n";
$offer_id = $apiResponse['response']['data']['OfferUrl']['offer_id'];
$name = $apiResponse['response']['data']['OfferUrl']['name'];
.
.
.
```